# Power supply circuit for two devices

Tags: voltage, power, current, voltage-divider, power-divider

I need to split the power from an AC/DC converter to two devices. The converter I have takes an AC input of 100 to 240V and outputs 48VDC and 30W power. I have one device that needs 48V and 30W and another that needs between 3 and 5V and can't exceed 15mA.

1. Is it possible to reach the requirements of both devices, and if so, what would the circuit look like?
2. If the above is not possible, I can lower the requirements for the first device, but I still don’t know what the circuit would need to look like. Any help?

Comment: Look for a DC-DC converter that can convert 48V to 5V and provide 15mA. You will have about 29.9W left for the 48V device.

Comment: If your 48VDC device is taking all 30 watts, there's nothing left over for the 3-5V device. It's not a great idea to operate right at the limit of a supply, it seems like yours is under sized.